# Ensuring that a file saves before databind

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a function that saves an XML file and then binds it to a gridview. My problem is that the gridview is updating before the file is done saving.

So far I've been able to get the save to occur first by inserting a 1 second pause, however, I realize that this is a terrible, not to mention unreliable, way of getting the desired result. My code currently looks like this

```
 editingFunction();

 gsXML.Save(Server.MapPath("~/xmlFile.xml"));

 System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);  // Ill-advised, I know...

 XmlDataSource1.Data = gsXML.OuterXml;
 XmlDataSource1.DataBind();
 updatePanel1.Update();
```

Does anyone know a better way to ensure that the save function occurs before the binding?

EDIT: It seems that I misdiagnosed the problem. The save function was in fact executing first, however, I needed to clear the XmlDataSource.Data first by calling 'XmlDataSource1.Data = null.' Thanks to Graffito for pointing this out!

Comment: How do you know that the code is updating the grid before saving the file, the control should not move to the next line if call to `Save` isn't completed. `Save` looks like synchronous call.

Comment: I came to that conclusion after noticing that the gridview would sometimes not reflect the changes made to the file. After inserting the 1 second pause, it worked consistently.

Comment: what is the type of `gsXML` ?

Comment: I declare it as follows: private static XmlDocument gsXML = new XmlDocument();

Comment: Was the gsXML already bound before you call the editing function ?

Comment: Yes, I'm re-binding it to reflect changes.

Comment: @Graffito Removing the second bind (in the code above) didn't help...

Comment: Before "XmlDataSource1.Data = gsXML.OuterXml", insert "XmlDataSource1.Data = null".

Comment: Awesome! That seems to have done the trick. Thanks! If you add this as an answer, I'll definitely give you credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the DataGridView is already bound to its source, the instruction "  XmlDataSource1.Data = gsXML.OuterXml" does not operate.

To force a new binding, remove the binding first:

```
 XmlDataSource1.Data = null.
 XmlDataSource1.Data = gsXML.OuterXml
```